# Como fazer um balanceamento de classes em um problema de regressão em machine learning com Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

Problema usando o *dataset* do livro "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow"

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml

*dataset* de preços de casas. Objetivo: criar uma modelo de previsão de preços de casas.

Obtive o histograma abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dá para ver que há um "desbalanceamento" de preços das casas.

Fazer "*resampling*" com 2 classes/classificacao é relativamente fácil. Agora como fazer o mesmo no problema acima, em que a classe não é binária? Cada valor de casa é uma classe...

Código fonte (é um jupyter notebook):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import sys #ver python path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

housing = pd.read_csv('/Dados/Estudo_ML/handson-ml-master/datasets/housing/housing.csv',dtype={"srcip":object ,})

housing.head(20)

# # Análise de dados exploratória e Pré-processamento
# 

#quero prever "median_house_value"


vars = ['longitude', 'latitude','housing_median_age','total_rooms','total_bedrooms',
       'population','households','median_income']

sns.pairplot(housing)

housing['median_house_value']#a classe!

housing

housing.isna().sum()
# Podemos ver que os dados faltantes estão exclusivamente na coluna 'total_bedrooms'


housing.isnull().sum()

housing['total_bedrooms']


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(housing.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='viridis',ax=ax)# dados faltantes:concentracao nas colunas

housing['median_house_value'].hist()#classes desbalanceadas?????? SIMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM


sns.boxplot(x='median_house_value',y='total_bedrooms',data =housing )


# Criando variáveis do tipo dummies!

housing.columns


housing.iloc[:,housing.columns.isin(('ocean_proximity','ocean_proximity')) ]##ocean_proximity : é uma variável categórica

pd.get_dummies(housing['ocean_proximity']) #Dummy


# # Escalonamento de variáveis 
# (importante para alg que calculam distâncias como a euclidiana (KNN...)


import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

type(housing['ocean_proximity'])

scaler.fit_transform(housing[['median_income']])



# # Normalizando

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

min_max_scaler.fit_transform(housing[['population']]) #normalize the columns of this dataframe where each value is between 0 and 1


# # Balanceamento (Resampling) e escalonamento do datset:

##Fazer balancemento no treinamento para equilibrar a qtd de amostras de casa de cada categoria de preco

housing[housing['median_house_value']>=100000].count()


housing[housing['median_house_value']>=500000].count()

housing['median_house_value'].hist()#classes desbalanceadas!

# # Abordagem escolhida: Down-sample Majority Class

from sklearn.utils import resample

# Separate majority and minority classes

df_majority_down = housing[housing.median_house_value<=300000]
df_minority_down = housing[housing.median_house_value>=400000]
```

Comment: Você está fazendo um algortimo para prever os preço: isso significa que é um algoritmo de regressão (ele cospe um número que é o preço previsto) ou um de classificação (ele cospe um número que é um bucket da faixa de preço)? Se for o de preço, porque você precisa fazer balanceamento? Você n tem classes, apenas valores finais, certo?

Comment: @Victor Capone: A dúvida começa aí... Faz sentido balanceamento em regressao? é que há faixas de preços que tem poucas casas...

Answer (score 3):

Não tenho vasta experiência no assunto mas, acredito que, nesse caso, se tratando de um problema de uso de regressão, na minha visão não há necessidade do uso de balanceamento de classes, até porque é possível notar que há valores finais (como dito nos comentários da pergunta) e não classes em si.

Talvez você possa usar algum dos algoritmos de regressão, como Support Vector Machines (SVM) ou Nearest Neighbors através do Scikit-learn.

Comment: Mas será que nao daria para criar "faixas de preço" como se fossem classes para fazer o balanceamento?

Answer (score -3):

Uma classe é a definição para um conjunto de atributos que diferenciam características próprias entre eles, como frutas, cores, marcas, etc. Tudo isso pode e deve ser balanceado para que não ocorra underfitting ou overfitting. Algo como o preço não se define como uma classe de algo, por isso ele não pode ser balanceado, mas pode ser normalizado, para que os números fiquem bem comportados, além de também ser retirados outliers.